# using entity frame work(code first approach) i am able to insert only one record out of 63 from a list?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I need to store 63 records into a db using entity frame work by passing a list object?

i tried to using  with add range method of DBCONTEXT

```
pdfcontext.Pdfannonation.AddRange(listPDFannotations);
```

i expect to store 63 records from list

Comment: i am able to store only one record

Comment: May you add more information so that people fully understand you. Is your list of `listPDFannotations` have unique Ids? Are you calling `pdfcontext.SaveChanges()` after adding? If so whats the value returned (number of rows affected) or does it throw an exception? Has the list not been obtained from the same `pdfcontext`? A bit more code will certainly be more helpful

Comment: I found out error and resolve the issue.